# Не работает input в Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, кодировка, input, utf

Всем доброго времени суток! Когда я пытаюсь использовать обычную команду input, то после запуска выдается вот такая вот ошибка:

```
 File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Данная ошибка происходит только при вызове input() в независимости от его содержимого. Скорее всего дело в кодировке, но без я без понятия как это устранить.

Comment: добавьте фрагмент собственного кода в вопрос, где стоит input()

Comment: Здравствуйте на Stack Overflow на русском. Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы **без явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).